# Window scroll event not firing in Firefox, only when linking to specific anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, anchor

The behavior is hard to comprehend but in Firefox, only for the first anchor, the window scroll event is not firing when called from another page.

Problem is here: [staging](http://r8n.mangrovestudios.com) - click on the "Intuitive" link under the masterhead.

Home page has link like this:

```
<a href="/features#intuitive"></a>
```

The javascript function uses the scroll event to collapsed the header:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(st) // <-- not fired in Firefox for anchor 'intuitive'    
  if (st > 330) {
   $('#sticky-nav-box').removeClass('container').addClass('sticky-nav-collapsed');
  } else {
   $('#sticky-nav-box').addClass('container').removeClass('sticky-nav-collapsed');
  }     
});
```

The problem is the link is correctly sending to the anchor, but the scroll event is not firing, hence the collapsing is not taking place.

Other anchor links work fine. I tried manually firing the scroll event after page load but that didn't resolve it. I also tried linking to dummy anchors.

This only happens in Firefox, when linking to the first row of content. If I link to the second anchor `<a class="anchor" id="learn-about-views"></a>`, it works. What is going on?

Comment: I can see loggings in FF32.0.3 and FF33.

Comment: @Teemu issue persists in FF 32.0.2, 32.0.3, 33.0. Do you see a logging after clicking on "intuitive" of homepage prior to any scrolling? The event should fire since the anchor is mid-page..

Comment: Yes, but looks like logging stops when `window.innerWidth` gets below 768.

Comment: @Teemu that's expected. The mobile design has a collapsed design in separate absolute-positioned elements. The current problem is desktop users on Firefox.